# Plot loss evolution during a single epoch in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

Does Keras have a built-in method to output (and later plot) the loss evolution during the training of a single epoch?

The usual method of using the function keras.callbacks.History() can output loss for each epoch. However in my case the training set is fairly large, and therefore I am passing a single epoch to the NN. Since I would like to plot the evolution of the training (and dev) loss during training, is there a way to do this?

I am currently solving this by dividing the training set into different batches and then training on each sequentially with a single epoch and saving the model each time. But maybe there is a built-in way to do this?

I am using TensorFlow backend.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a callback for this purpose.

Using the [Keras MNIST CNN example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) (not copying the whole code here), with the following changes/additions:

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class TestCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, test_data):
        self.test_data = test_data

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        x, y = self.test_data
        loss, acc = self.model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=0)
        print('\nTesting loss: {}, acc: {}\n'.format(loss, acc))

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=1,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[TestCallback((x_test, y_test))]
         )
```

for evaluating the test/validation set on each batch end, we get this:

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/1

Testing loss: 0.0672039743446745, acc: 0.9781

  128/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 7484s - loss: 0.1450 - acc: 0.9531

/var/venv/DSTL/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:120: UserWarning: Method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch update (15.416976). Check your callbacks.
  % delta_t_median)


Testing loss: 0.06644540682602673, acc: 0.9781

  256/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 7476s - loss: 0.1187 - acc: 0.9570

/var/venv/DSTL/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:120: UserWarning: Method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch update (15.450395). Check your callbacks.
  % delta_t_median)


Testing loss: 0.06575664376271889, acc: 0.9782
```

However, as you will probably see for yourself, this has the severe drawback of **slowing down** the code significantly (and duly producing some relevant warnings). As a compromise, if you are OK with getting only the *training* performance at the end of each batch, you could use a slightly different callback:

```
class TestCallback2(Callback):
    def __init__(self, test_data):
        self.test_data = test_data

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        print()  # just a dummy print command
```

The results now (replacing `callbacks=[TestCallback2((x_test, y_test))` in `model.fit()`) are much faster, but giving only the training metrics at the end of each batch:

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/1

  128/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 346s - loss: 0.8503 - acc: 0.7188
  256/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 355s - loss: 0.8496 - acc: 0.7109
  384/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 339s - loss: 0.7718 - acc: 0.7396
  [...]
```

**UPDATE**

All the above may be fine, but the resulting losses & accuracies are not stored anywhere, and hence they cannot be plotted; so, here is another callback solution that actually stores the metrics on the training set:

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class Histories(Callback):

    def on_train_begin(self,logs={}):
        self.losses = []
        self.accuracies = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.accuracies.append(logs.get('acc'))


histories = Histories()

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=1,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[histories]
         )
```

which results in the metrics at the end of each batch during training being stored in `histories.losses` and `histories.accuracies`, respectively - here are the first 5 entries of each:

```
histories.losses[:5]
# [2.3115866, 2.3008101, 2.2479887, 2.1895032, 2.1491694]

histories.accuracies[:5]
# [0.0703125, 0.1484375, 0.1875, 0.296875, 0.359375]
```

Comment: I implemented a mix of your original and your edited answer to use this on training loss and validation loss. I then modified the on_batch_end method with an if statement so as to perform this every 20 iterations, in order not to slow the training too much.

Answer (score 3):

a great way for real-time control loss during training is livelossplot, you can install in by pip

```
pip install livelossplot
```

[image: image description]