# Custom callback after each epoch to log certain information

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I know how to [save the model after every epoch](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/callback_model_checkpoint.html):

```
savemodel = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='models/model_{epoch:02d}-{loss:.2f}.h5')
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=4, epochs=32, verbose=1, callbacks=[savemodel])
```

How to have a custom callback function to log certain informations:

```
def write_metrics(): 
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:  # append to the log file
        f.write('{epoch:02d}: loss = {loss:.1f}')

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=4, epochs=32, verbose=1, callbacks=[savemodel, write_metrics])
```

?

With this code it won't work because `{loss}` and `{epoch}` are not defined in `f.write('{epoch:02d}: loss = {loss:.1f}')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot loss evolution during a single epoch in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205315/plot-loss-evolution-during-a-single-epoch-in-keras)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution, by subclassing `Callback`:

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class MyLogger(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        with open('log.txt', 'a+') as f:
            f.write('%02d %.3f\n' % (epoch, logs['loss']))
```

then

```
mylogger = MyLogger()
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs=32, verbose=1, callbacks=[mylogger])
```

or even

```
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs=32, verbose=1, callbacks=[MyLogger()])
```

Comment: I see at some places `logs={}` i.e, a dictionary and `logs=None` as in the example you've provided, Can you explain the `logs` argument and how in your example it is able to get the loss using `logs['loss']`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to define a function (or even use an explicit callback) for this, as such info is automatically returned by the `fit` method; from the [docs](https://keras.io/callbacks/#history):

> **History**
>
> `keras.callbacks.History()`
>
> Callback that records events into a `History` object.
>
> This callback is automatically applied to every Keras model. The
>   `History` object gets returned by the `fit` method of models.

You don't even need to explicitly import anything; what you need is just:

```
hist = model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=4, epochs=32, verbose=1, callbacks=[savemodel]) # no other specific callback
```

and `hist.history` will contain the loss and any other metrics of interest you may have defined (e.g. accuracy), for the training and validation (if exists) sets, at the end of each epoch, which you can subsequently save into a file.

See [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/) for detailed examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in fact I would like to log these informations *explicitly after each epoch*. Thus the need for a callback. Why? Because sometimes the training doesn't finish until the last epoch (for example because the GPU cloud computing is expensive and I want to stop before the last epoch has finished, or because the server has crashed or connection has been interrupted). Thus the return value `hist` might not be reached.

Comment: @Basj I think it will - give it a try: do an experiment where you artificially break the execution, and see what is contained in `hist` ;)

Comment: @Basj see the general callback entry in the [docs](https://keras.io/callbacks/#callback) - the relevant info is actually passed directly from the logs at the end of each epoch, so even if interrupted prematurely, the info will still be there (I would demonstrate it as part of the answer, but I don't have access right now)...

Answer (score 0):

A more straightforward approach to getting logs through Callbacks is using a `CSVlogger` callback.

### CSVLogger class

```
tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(filename, separator=",", append=False)
```

Callback that streams epoch results to a CSV file.

Supports all values represented as a string, including 1D iterables such as np.ndarray.

Example

```
csv_logger = CSVLogger('training.log')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[csv_logger])
```

Arguments

- filename: Filename of the CSV file, e.g. 'run/log.csv'.
- separator: String used to separate elements in the CSV file.
- append: Boolean. True: append if file exists (useful for continuing training). False: overwrite the existing file.